# C# - Add/Remove with ListBoxes

Tags: winforms, listbox, addition, move

Right now I have 3 RichTextBox(es) with text in them. I am taking this text from these boxes and splitting each line and adding each separate line to its corresponding ListBox.  Here is my code for that:

```
private void listFormatHelper()
{
    // Splits the lines in the rich text boxes
    var listOneLines = placementOneRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
    var listTwoLines = placementTwoRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');
    var listUserLines = userDefinedRichTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

    // Resest the text in the listboxes
    placementOneListBox.ResetText();
    placementTwoListBox.ResetText();
    userDefinedListBox.ResetText();

    // Set the selection mode to multiple and extended.
    placementOneListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    placementTwoListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    userDefinedListBox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

    // Shutdown the painting of the ListBox as items are added.
    placementOneListBox.BeginUpdate();
    placementTwoListBox.BeginUpdate();
    userDefinedListBox.BeginUpdate();

    // Display the items in the listbox.
    placementOneListBox.DataSource = listOneLines;
    placementTwoListBox.DataSource = listTwoLines;
    userDefinedListBox.DataSource = listUserLines;

    // Allow the ListBox to repaint and display the new items.
    placementOneListBox.EndUpdate();
    placementTwoListBox.EndUpdate();
    userDefinedListBox.EndUpdate();
}
```

---

After the above code, each ListBox has the specified data in it on separate lines.  However, what I am trying to do is add buttons buttons, that when clicked move the selected list item to the specified ListBox.

---

***VISUAL LAYOUT OF LISTBOXES:***

```
placementOneListBox                userDefinedListBox                placementTwoListBox
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|                 |                |                 |               |                 |
|_________________|                |_________________|               |_________________|
```

So, what I am trying to do is have a button that says "move right" or "move left" and it takes the currently selected item (preferably **items** for multiselection) and moves it to either the left or to the right ListBox. However, for the placementOneListBox the "move left" button will not work and for the placementTwoListBox the "move right" button will not work.  I tried this way below (which did not work):

```
private void placementOneMoveRightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentItemText = placementOneListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
    var currentItemIndex = placementOneListBox.SelectedIndex;

    userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(currentItemText);
    placementOneListBox.Items.Remove(currentItemIndex);
    placementOneListBox.Items.RemoveAt(placementOneListBox.Items.IndexOf(placementOneListBox.SelectedItem));
}
```

I also tried this way (which also did not work):

```
private void placementOneMoveRightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str;
    str = placementOneListBox.SelectedItems.ToString();
    placementOneListBox.Items.Remove(placementOneListBox.SelectedItems);
    userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(str);
}
```

---

***THE REASON WHY THEY DO NOT WORK***:

Whenever I am running the program and I click the "move right" button (for either code cases above) I get the following error:

```
"Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."
```

---

***QUESTIONS***

- Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in this?
- Can someone show/explain what is happening with the "DataSource property" and how I can get around it?

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms? WebForms? WPF? Silverlight? XNA? Phone?

Comment: I am doing this a form. not a webForm

Comment: You didn't answer the question, but since you're using the word "form" I'm going to assume you mean WinForms, and add the appropriate tag to this question.

Comment: Sorry I meant WinForms. Oops :/

Comment: doing this is Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to modify the dataset while it is bound to the listbox. What you need to do instead is recreate the dataset and then bind that new dataset to the listbox.

Sorry Colton, had a meeting at work.

I am not sure what kind of data you are working with, but here is an example of removing a name and adding a name to a ListBox:

```
private class Names
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Names(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // Form Load Event
{
    List<Names> names = new List<Names>();

    names.Add(new Names("John"));
    names.Add(new Names("Suzy"));
    names.Add(new Names("Mary"));
    names.Add(new Names("Steve"));

    listBox1.DataSource = names;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Names> names = new List<Names>();
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        Names name = (Names)item;
        if (name.Name.Equals("Mary")) // Remove Mary
            continue;

        names.Add(name);
    }

    names.Add(new Names("Joe")); // Add Joe

    listBox1.DataSource = names;
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
}
```

So what I'm doing is in the Form Load event, I'm populating my listbox with fresh names and setting the datasource to my List object. When the button is clicked, I am creating a NEW List and populating with the same names except for poor Mary. She's out of the list. I then Add Joe to the list and then set the datasource again. The important thing to take away from this is that once you have binded a data source to a listbox, you CANNOT modify that data source in any way. You must create a new datasource and then rebind to the new source. Does this make more sense now?

Comment: How would I got about doing this?

Comment: @Colton - One second and I will post an example

Comment: cemanind is right.What he meant to say is use listOneLines,listTwoLines,listUserLines instead of add/remove from lstbox Controls.

Comment: @arjunshetty2020 - How could I go about this properly?

Comment: No problem :). Yes this makes more sense. The data I am using is a string that takes up the entire line (about 320 pixels wide). I am adding the data not manually like you have above "names.Add(new Names("John"));" but rather from a RichTextBox that is split by lines. I will work with what you have given me! Ill let you know if I am able to figure some things out. Thank you icemanind! :)

Comment: @icemanind - Is there any possibility you could show me how you would go about this with two ListBoxes getting data from two RichTextBoxes? Also, with the two ListBoxes instead of adding/removing the buttons would be switching the list item from one ListBox to the other?

Comment: @Colton - It would be pretty much the same. You would create an empty list then you would use the foreach loop like I have in my example, but you would iterate through the second listbox (listBox2.Items), adding items from the second list box to the first listBox1. If you need me to edit my answer and add an addition example, let me know and I will

Comment: @icemanind - I am thinking about posting the code I am using now as an answer below... I realized what I am doing is not very efficient as I am storing data in places I believe I do not need.. any optimization would be great I suppose. Would you mind helping me work through my code?

Comment: @icemanind - I forgot I can't reply to my answer for another 4 hours.. lol. is there an easier way to contact you [assuming you are willing to help.. :)]?

Answer (score 3):

refer following article at code project : [How to Move List Box Items to another List Box in C#.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/List_Box_Control.aspx)

also you can look at [so quetion : how-to-remove-selected-items-from-listbox-when-a-datasource-is-assigned-to-it-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709562/how-to-remove-selected-items-from-listbox-when-a-datasource-is-assigned-to-it-in)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
private void placementOneMoveRightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < placementOneListBox.SelectedItems.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = placementOneListBox.Items[i];
        if(item.Selected)
        {
            placementOneListBox.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            userDefinedListBox.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the mode to multi select. Also you must have an item selected in the list box when you hit the button...